# How to disable Windows 10 feature when building QtWebEngine 5.8 using VS 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, build, qtwebengine, qt5.8

QtWebEngine does not support play mp3 by default, so I need to build it from source, to enable mp3 support.

My environment:

- Windows 7 64 bit SP 1
- VS 2015 Community
- Qt WebEngine 5.8

Building failed due to error:

> d:\sdks\qt\qtwebengine-opensource-src-5.8.0\src\3rdparty\chromium\base\win\win_util.cc(26): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'uiviewsettingsinterop.h': No such file or directory

I did some research, this header is part of Windows 10 SDK. I tried to eanble Win 10 SDK feature in VS 2015, but failed.

Now I want to know, can I disable Win 10 support in Qt WebEngine configuration? Since I just need it on Win 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't disable it. Because Win 10 SDK is required to build Chromium 53

I cant find official documentation about chromium 53. But, please see this document https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/windows_build_instructions.md#Visual-Studio

Comment: As said in my question, I failed to install Windows 10 SDK (Seems not compatible with Win 7). Now I want to know, if I can disable Win 10 support in WebEngine configuration, so I can build it without Win 10 SDK?

Comment: You can't disable it. Because Win 10 SDK is required to build Chromium 53

Comment: Is there official document for this?

Comment: I cant find official documentation about chromium 53. But, please see this document https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/windows_build_instructions.md#Visual-Studio

Comment: Thank you for the information. Please add this to your answer, so I can accept it.